# How to show SMS coming from a SMS gateway in my site

Tags: web, sms, feed

i need to show SMS coming from an available SMS gateway in my site.Is there any good way to achieve this?  Do SMS gateway service providers provide such a option such as a RSS feed or something when we send a SMS through the gateway which we can integrate to our site as a news feed?or what kind of options i can try!

Comment: are you already using sms gateway or you still want to select a gateway?

Comment: its depend on my client they told me that they are already using a one (didn't tell exactly what and still the project is in planing stage) and if possible i was told to use that. problem is whether the provider provides this option? (i am new to this. so i don't know whether these providers usually provides this kind of facility?) if not what kind of workaround i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple SMS gateways available, like Twilio, Sms enabler , clickatell . they provide different kinds of options for integrating sms into your system.

I would tell you my personal experience,when i had to make such a system. i wrote my own script and used a modem with a system to send and recieve sms using a third party tool.

Comment: Thanks! @captain_a i'll try on it! because the client needs to use an available gateway they have being using for some time.and its from a local service provider i think! what is the language you used! as this is for a web site is java good?

Comment: well , that totally depends on what kind of service your provider is giving, 
i made my system using php for web , and the third party tool with a modem for messaging.